# How do I add swap automatically when creating instances on Ganeti 2?

Tags: debian, virtualization

I'm using the `ganeti2` package on Debian 5. Instance creation goes pretty smoothly, except that it doesn't configure a swap disk automatically, and I'd like it to do so.

Googling around, I found absolutely no one with my problem, which makes me suspect a fundamental mistake on my part, but I can't figure out what. The Ganeti 2 documentation also doesn't touch the subject, though previous versions had an instance creation parameter for that.

So, how can I do it? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is three years old - but in case anyone else comes across it with the same issue, it looks like Pietro Abate has a ganeti-instance-debootstrap hook for doing this, which is pretty automatic:

http://mancoosi.org/~abate/add-swap-hook-ganetideboostrapinstance

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely explicitly telling it to just create one disk, as the `--swap-size` option is now deprecated. You should be able to add a swap partition like so:

```
--disks 0:size=200G --disks 1:size=2G ...[more config]
```

on instance creation. Make the usual adjustments after the instance is created -- `mkswap`, `swapon`, `/etc/fstab` etc. Alternatively, you can create a swap file on the instance itself from within the filesystem and keep your creation more or less the same:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap_file bs=1M count=2048
mkswap /swap_file
swapon /swap_file
echo '/swap_file swap swap defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

Comment: No, I'm adding two disks. And I do have a rather tricky script to do it, which definitely does not qualify as "automatic". I need to check for a second disk, get the UUID, export it, fdisk it, de-export it (and this runs in background, and may cause problems unless there's a sleep), and only then mkswap/swapon/fstab.